# Grouping objects after query in django views

Tags: django, view

I have a Post table and each of these posts may have one of three types; foo, bar, or foobar.  If I extract all the the data from the posts table, how could I assign each of these types to the variable AFTER I query all the objects.

```
def posts(request):
    posts = Posts.objects.all()
```

what i don't want to do

```
def posts(request):
    a = Posts.objects.all().filter(type=foo)
    b = Posts.objects.all().filter(type=bar)
    c = Posts.objects.all().filter(type=foobar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply different filters on same query:

```
posts = Posts.objects.all()
foo_posts = posts.filter(type='foo')
bar_posts = posts.filter(type='bar')
foobar_posts = posts.filter(type='foobar')
```

This means you can do this:

```
categories = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
filtered_posts = Posts.objects.filter(**my_custom_query)
category_queries = {}
for category in categories:
    category_queries[category] = filtered_posts.filter(type=category)
```

Comment: thats what I wrote I didn't want to do

Comment: i have alot of processing for the data afterwards, and actually have more types than just 3 so would have to run the processing on each of them as opposed to running the process on all posts then appropriating the types. Idk if its slower but it adds exponentially more lines to the code and makes it very redundant

Comment: I still don't understand why can't you simply iterate through types and do the processing in the loop?

Comment: the answer is: I can. but for the sake of cleaner code, I wanted to know if its possible the other way

Comment: It is possible, but you will have to implement a custom [Queryset subclass](http://adam.gomaa.us/blog/2009/feb/16/subclassing-django-querysets/index.html).

Comment: @niekas Have you actually checked this hits the database only once? I'm pretty sure that is not the case. Both versions of your code will hit the database exactly three times. You can use Django Debug Toolbar to check.

Comment: @Ludwik Trammer you are right. Applying new filter requires a separate database hit. But using ``category_queries`` dict in further code does not require new database hits.

Comment: To be more precise: both version of your actual code will hit the database exactly zero times, but later, when you'll want to actually access values in `foo_posts`, `bar_posts` and `foobar_posts` / `category_queries['foo']`, `category_queries['bar']` and `category_queries['foobar']` there will be a separate database query issued for each one. After those three initial hits, there will be no additional hits, that is true.